# How to override window.open?

Tags: javascript

I was wodering, is it possible to override window.open? I want to a add delay to every window.open call

Let's say one piece of code opens window using onClick, the other one using window.open, so is it possible to add like `setTimeout` to global `window.open`?

Comment: `open` is a writeable property simply need to set it to some function `window.open=function(){}`

Comment: U got me wrong, what i want to do is to add a global override, for every different calls. Let's say one script uses window.open and i can't edit it, but the second script should add a delay to the first one, and every other.

Comment: That is the only way to override it. As long as the first script doesnt store the original functiion it will call yours. If it does store it you would need to make your script execute before the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save a reference to `window.open`, then overwrite it with your own function that calls the saved reference after the timeout:

```
const origOpen = window.open;
window.open = (url) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    origOpen(url);
  }, 1000);
};


window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

(cannot embed into live snippet due to sandboxing constraints, but you can see a live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ok8g9xh/))

Comment: Works great, will it work in other <script> </script> tags too if i set it at the very front of the page?

Comment: Yep, as long as it gets reassigned first